# convert dataset to list<double> and list<string> C#

Tags: c#, list, dataset

my data looks like this:

```
+=======+========+
| year  |sales   |
+=======+========+
| 2008  |100000  |
| 2009  |120040  |
| 2010  |239000  |
| 2011  |300900  |
| 2012  |200900  |
+=======+========+
```

can I convert a dataset to list of double and string? the first column of the dataset will be `list<string>` and the second column is `list<double>`

is there any solution? thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you loop over DataSet your almost there.

Comment: Keeping two lists connected by index is not usually a good design. And any time you see a monetary value (a name like "sales" indicates money) you should use the Decimal type instead of double.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wonder why a year is a string, however...

```
List<string> years   = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0))
                            .ToList();
List<double> doubles = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(r => r.Field<double>(1))
                            .ToList();
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

You can use the [`Field` extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) method with the column's ordinal in the `DataRow` or via it's name: `r.Field<string>("year")`

Comment: It's better to specify `r.Field<string>("year")` and same for sales.

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Edited my answer to take that into account. Used the ordinal since OP mentioned them first.

Comment: Ok..I didn't notice that.. +1 for that..@TimSchmelter

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
List<string> years   = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(n => n.Field<string>(0))
                            .ToList();
```

And `(1)` for `sales` column.

Don't remember to add `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` namespace. Also look at from MSDN [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) method.

> Returns an IEnumerable object, where the generic parameter T is
>   DataRow. This object can be used in a LINQ expression or method query.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
var myyear = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(r => new {
                                 column1 = r.Field<string>("year")
                                 });

List<string> year = myyear.ToList();
```

2)

```
var mysales = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(r => new {
                                  column2 = r.Field<double>("sales")
                                 });

List<double> sales = mysales.ToList();
```